# Number sequence: 202500, 5184, 32400, 12960,?

Tags: number-sequence

**Can you solve my first selfmade number sequence ?**

> 202500, 5184, 32400, 12960, ?

1. Hint:

> The first three are all square numbers.

2. Hint:

> The tail of the solution might be confusing.

3. Hint

> How to get $n$ with $(n-1)$ and $(n-2)$ ?

Comment: Just to double check, the order matters?

Comment: Note: these are all rot13(erthyne ahzoref nxn unzzvat ahzoref)

Comment: @RShields rot13(nyy jvgu gur fnzr ahzore bs cevzr snpgbef)

Comment: rot13(guerr gb gur cbjre bs sbhe) @ArnaudMortier

Comment: Yes, the order is important.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on the observation by rhsquared, the next number is

> $\sqrt{2^9 3^8 5^3} = 6480 \sqrt{10} \approx 20491.559$

Reasoning

> Each element of the sequence is the geometric mean of the previous two.
>  That is for $n>2$, $$ a_n = \sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}$$

Answer (score 5):

(Partial) It looks like all the numbers are

> Regular numbers, i.e. they can be represented as 2^i·3^j·5^k or
>  202500 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^4
>  5184 = 2^6 * 3^4 * 5^0
>  32400 = 2^4 * 3^4 * 5^2
>  12960 = 2^5 * 3^4 * 5^1
>  We can see that all the numbers contain 3^4 and also for all of them the sum of the powers equals 10.
>  So the answer will be in the form 2^i * 3^4 * 5^j, where i + j = 6, with one of the following combinations: 
>  0,6 where the result is 1265625
>  1,5 where the result is 506250
>  3,3 where the result is 81000

Comment: Good observation ! But the solution has decimal places.